# MySQL to SQLite converter

Tags: mysql, sqlite, converters

I have two tables

```
regions(id, name)
countries(id, name, region_id)
```

which is in MySQL format and i want to convert it into SQLite database. I have tried a few softwares but i am not able to get it to convert.

Is there any easy wat to convert them considering its a fairly simple tables.

I had a look at the following links

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools

http://dbconvert.com/convert-sqlite-to-mysql-pro.php

Either the software is paid or i am not able to get them to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776). It works on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.fileguru.com/DBConvert-For-SQLite---MySQL/info
I hope this is what u r looking for.Please check it out.

Comment: yeah i have installed it. it just exports 50 records :D i dont wanna buy the software bcos its more like one time use.

Comment: I beleave that there is nothing like FREE in this world...  :)

Comment: thats when open source was introduced :D